# Typedef struct implementation

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Can anyone explain the meaning of the code and give an example how to use it?
I can understand `foo[100]`, but not `bar`.

```
typedef struct{
   int a,b;
} CELL, *PCELL;

CELL foo[100];
PCELL bar(int x, CELL y);
```

Comment: Yes, it is a homework

Comment: bar is a function that gets two parameters an int and CELL and return *PCELL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
PCELL bar(int x, CELL y);
```

is a function declaration. It means that `bar` will take in an `int` and a `CELL` as parameters, and it will return a pointer to a `CELL` as a return value. The actual body of the function will be defined later.

Comment: Thank you very match, I understand it now. Before I thought bar is a variable not a function. I will accept your answer